# Sort array in Θ(n) complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, time-complexity, insertion-sort

> Prove that an array A of size n can be sorted in Θ(n) when it has O(n) inversions.

I don't know exactly what this question is asking.  My best guess is that we use insertion sort on a presorted input and that way we can achieve Θ(n) complexity by sorting.  Is this what the question is asking me?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question ...?

Comment: "my guess is that we use insertion sort on a presorted input and that way we can achieve O(n) complexity". Well, the input is not completely pre-sorted. (In that case, there would be no inversions.) There are O(n) inversions here as per the question. So it could be something like 5,4,7,6,10,9. Use the hint below and prove that sorting something like this can happen in \theta(n) time.

Comment: @user2321926 how did you do on the exam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a hint - the runtime of insertion sort is Θ(n + I), where n is the number of elements and I is the number of inversions in the array. What happens if you insertion sort the array, given that it only has O(n) inversions? What will the time complexity be?

Hope this helps!

Comment: in this case the complexity would be Θ(2n) which is just Θ(n)?